# Why is redirecting Python output to file so slow?

Tags: python, redirect, logging, stdout, output

I wrote a simple Python script to collect some system metrics and ship to Graphite.  I also wrote some print statements into the script for debug purposes while debugging and decided to keep them in there for logging.

The script runs through some basic OS commands, prints results to console, sends them to carbon-cache, then sleeps for 10 seconds and starts all over again.

When I run the script in the foreground, it prints the correct output to stdout every 10 seconds as I would expect. Running the script with `python ports.py >> /var/log/ports.log` results in /very/ slow redirection to the log file.  If I tail the file I don't see output for minutes at a time, and the output is "choppy," that is to say, the output may be cut off, as seen below.

```
foo:/var/log# tailf open_ports.log


stats.foo.open_ports.broadsoft1 1 1378477047.01
stats.foo.open_ports.broadsoft2 1 1378477047.01
stats.foo.open_ports.bash 15 1378477047.01
stats.foo.open_ports.flash 16 1378477047.01
stats.foo.open_ports.cash 16 1378477047.01
stats.foo.open_ports
```

When I expect to see this:

```
stats.foo.open_ports.broadsoft1 1 1378477036.44
stats.foo.open_ports.broadsoft2 1 1378477036.44
stats.foo.open_ports.bash 14 1378477036.44
stats.foo.open_ports.flash 16 1378477036.44
stats.foo.open_ports.cash 16 1378477036.44
stats.foo.open_ports.NS2 13 1378477036.44
stats.foo.open_ports.NMS 16 1378477036.44
stats.foo.open_ports.Netsun1 13 1378477036.44
stats.foo.open_ports.Cacti 16 1378477036.44

Metrics sent.
```

Why does this happen and what can I do to fix this?  As far as I can tell it's not affecting anything but I'd like to know why it does this and what I can do to correct this behavior.

Comment: Buffering. If you need to read it in realtime, flush stdout after writing.

Comment: Consider using the logging module.

Comment: That makes sense but if it's Python buffering, wouldn't I see the same thing in both stdout and the file created by the stdout redirect?

Comment: @devOpsEv Not necessarily. The `print` function might check whether the `stdout` file is a `tty` and flush more often in this case. If you want to have some guarantee about when you'll see the output then you **must** `flush` manually. It's a matter of specifying `flush=True` when calling `print`(in python3.3; for previous version you have to `sys.stdout.flush()`).

Comment: For cpython, its the underlying c libraries. If the output is a tty, it line buffers, otherwise it block buffers.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, everyone.  I did end up using the logging module as it allows for much nicer and more concise output.